# In Prism, RegisterTypes is called before constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

In `MainActivity.cs` and `AppDelegate.cs` I initialize the `Configuration` object like so:

```
LoadApplication(new App(Configuration.GetConfiguration, new AndroidInitializer()));
```

I insert that object in the constructor of the `App` class.

I want to register that same object in the `RegisterTypes` method.

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    public App(IConfiguration configuration, IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        // Here Configuration is null.
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

        // Need to access configuration again.
        var restClient = new RestClient(Configuration.BaseApiUrl);
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<IRestClient>(restClient);
    }
}
```

Within `RegisterTypes` method, `Configuration` is null because it is called before constructor.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two ways to do what you need depending on exactly what it is that you're trying to accomplish with `IConfiguration`:

If all you're doing is registering the instance of `IConfiguration` then you should be registering it in IPlatformInitializer and not in your app. For example you might have:

```
public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitalizer
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistery.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(new iOSConfiguration());
    }
}
```

If you need to specifically access something about `IConfiguration` and you could follow the first pattern and just resolve it to do what you need to do... otherwise you could do something like:

```
public class iOSInitializer : IPlatformInitalizer, IConfiguration
{
    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistery.RegisterInstance<IConfiguration>(this);
    }
}
```

Then in your app you could simply do:

```
var configuration = (IConfiguration)PlatformInitializer
```

Comment: Registering in `IPlatformInitializer.RegisterTypes` is the solution if the `IPlatformInitializer.RegisterTypes` is guaranteed to be called before `PrismApplication.RegisterTypes` on all platforms. Do you think it is?

Comment: Correct. Remember `IPlatformInitializer` specifically exists to allow you to handle platform specific registrations.

Comment: I updated the question because I need to resolve IConfiguration within `PrismApplication.RegisterTypes` to access some of its properties. With your code I would call `configuration = Container.Resolve<IConfiguration>(); apiUrl = configuration.ApiUrl;` Do you think it's guaranteed to not be null?

Comment: @Jam if you need to actually utilize properties from the configuration just use the second example for how to handle the scenario... if you have it as some other type completely that you've registered in `IPlatformInitializer`, then you can simply call `Container.Resolve<IConfiguration>()` in RegisterTypes in your App, so long as you're not using Autofac which is an Immutable Container meaning that the container isn't actually created until after RegisterTypes. There are more complex container specific registration methods you could also use to work around that as well.