# Prism 7.1 : IContainerProvider & IContainerRegistry

Tags: c#, wpf, instance, unity-container, prism

Newer developer here, working on my second application, and the first using Prism 7.1.

I am hoping to get a little assistance with properly accessing a ViewModel registered within Shell.xaml.cs.

Here is what I am working with:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App
{
  protected override Window CreateShell()
  {
    return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
  }
  protected override void RegisterTypes(IContanerRegistry containerRegistry)
  {
    containerRegistry.Register<ShellViewModel>();
  }
}
```

**Shell.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Shell : MetroWindow
{
    public Shell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }
```

I am able to access my ViewModel's properties just fine, through doing the following:

```
var shellVM_Instance = containerProvider.Resolve<ShellViewModel>();
shellVM_Instance.IsBusy = false;
```

The code will compile, but it will not run. When I run the code, it tells me that ShellViewModel, from within the above var shellVM_Instance, is referencing a null object of type ShellViewModel. This leads me to think that I did not properly register the ViewModel with IContainerRegistry.

Can anyone offer any assistance?

I would like to avoid using a Bootstrapper class, and take advantage of what Prism 7.1 has to offer ([Brian's Release Notes](https://brianlagunas.com/whats-new-prism-7-1/))

I appreciate any guidance here, and your patience while I try to wrap my mind around Prism and its true potential.

**EDIT:**

I see that IContainerRegistry has a RegisterInstance method..

```
void RegisterInstance(Type type, object instance);
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out the syntax. My attempts:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        ShellViewModel shell_VM = new ShellViewModel();
        containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ShellViewModel, shell_VM>();
    }
```

Thank you!

-Chris

Comment: Try out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106630/in-prism-registertypes-is-called-before-constructor

Comment: @bakunet Thank you. I am going to see if I can implement something like this within my application.

Comment: You are welcommed. I use Autofac IoC and I use Prism ony for EventAggregator, but under this link you can find decent examples how you use it for Prism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [`IContainerRegistry`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Ioc/IContainerRegistry.cs) and [`IContainerRegistryExtensions`](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Prism.Core/Ioc/IContainerRegistryExtensions.cs).

So you can do either

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance( typeof( ShellViewModel ), shell_VM );
```

or generically with the extension methods

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance<ShellViewModel>( shell_VM );
```

Even better register as singleton, just in case you have any dependencies (that you would have to resolve yourself, otherwise)

```
containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ShellViewModel>();
```

That being said, you're doing it all wrong from the first place. Rarely, a view model is a singleton. Instead make your view models communicate through a third party singleton (either `EventAggregator` or one of your own services). For your case, I suggest something like this:

```
public interface IApplicationBusyIndicator : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool IsBusy { get; set; }
}
```

Then make the shell view model watch for changes to `IsBusy` and activate or deactivate your wait-overlay, while other view models or services set `IsBusy` while they're doing stuff. You can make it more sophisticated, of course, if you happen to have more than one actor that makes the application busy and those actions overlap...

```
public interface IApplicationBusySetter
{
    IDisposable RequestBusy();
}
```

Then show the wait-screen until all of the requests are disposed.

Comment: Thank you, @Haukinger. I was not aware of that documentation for the two interfaces. And yeah, I can see why you may say I am doing things completely wrong. I am currently using IEventAggregator and proper ViewModel registration with their views. Where I think I went wrong was linking my ViewModels/Models to the same IEventAggregator, as two of my Models were referencing different instances of the same ViewModel. I will go back and ensure they are using the same IEventAggregator. Thank you again!

Comment: links are dead.